# TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'name' of function '

Tags: angular

I was trying to type something in the input box but when I filled in my first letter it says `cannot assign to read only property`.

Here is my code

This is the code of the component:
[image]

This is the input type:
[image]

This is what is sitting in the topic:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're not initializing the `var topic: Topic` which you are using to bind to `<input [(ngModel)]...>`. To get your current version working you would have to bind to `selectedTopic` instead and call your `createNewContact()` in the `ngOnInit()`.

See: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kxd2ze